# Extract data with a cron task - file with title like "name_of_file-yyyymmdd.xz"

Tags: cron

I would like to extract some data from a file which is create each day at 3am.
The title of the file looks like this : "name_of_file-yyyymmdd.xz" ( y for year, m for month and d for day).
For my test, i try to extract this data every minutes with a cron task :

```
*/1 * * * * echo"`date -d 'yesterday'`">>/tmp/result.txt && xzcat /path_to_file/file-"`date -d 'yesterday' +%Y%m%d`".xz | wc -l >>/tmp/result.txt
```

But I have this error : "Syntax Error : premature end of file".
I don't understand because when i write "xzcat /path_to_file/file-"`date -d 'yesterday' +%Y%m%d`".xz | wc -l" without a cron task ( on the command window) it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution, if you want to make the same application, you must put a "\" in front of each "%" because it can be interpreted like a return to the line.